# The Jenkins tunnel address which I specify in the Jenkins->Configure Cloud does not seem to work. Can someone help me with the same?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-jenkins-plugin

I have a kubernetes cluster running on GKE and a Jenkins server running on a GCP instance.
I am using the Kubernetes plugin to dynamically create pods on the kubernetes cluster. I created a pipeline(Declarative syntax) for the same. 
So I am aware that the Jenkins slave agents communicates with the Jenkins master on port 50000.
[A snip of the configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBtYq.png)

But for some reason when I viewed the logs for the JNLP container creates by Jenkins, I received an exception - tcpSlaveAgentListener not found.
[A snip of the container log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njcRm.png)
According to the above image, I assume the tunneling is unsuccessful as it is trying to connect to http://34.90.46.204:8080/tcpSlaveAgentListener/ whereas it should connect to http://34.90.46.204:50000/tcpSlaveAgentListener/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a lazy question for me to ask, but I solved the issue.

In the Manage Jenkins-> Configure Global Security settings:

For the option on setting a port for TCP inbound agents: unselect the disable option which is selected by default and then provide a port for the inbound agents to interact on (50000).
[A snip of the configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXYaF.png) 
Jenkins uses a TCP port to communicate with agents connected inbound. If you're going to use inbound agents, you can allow the system to randomly select a port at launch (this avoids interfering with other programs, including other Jenkins instances). As it's hard for firewalls to secure a random port, you can instead specify a fixed port number and configure your firewall accordingly.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: can anyone tell how to configure in case of jenkins running as windows service ( 127.0.0.1:8080 ) outside minikube cluster

Comment: Saved me. Note: After plugin update this setting can flip to random.